# How to do data analysis using Python, of a file with thousands of dictionaries in each line

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I currently have a file with 5 thousand lines, with one dictionary in each line. All dictionaries have the same fields. My question is:

Should I learn SQL to store this data and do that analysis with it, or is using the file I've got good enough, and I should just use pandas or some other module to do data analysis.

I'm really lost on which path should I take.

Comment: It depends on what and how often you'll have to access the data, modify it, add data etc. I don't think there is a one line answer to this. 5000 lines isn't much and sqlite would be the lightweight solution that's considerably more reliable then `f.open`

Comment: I understand it's quite a subjective question. I'll won't need to modify it too much, my plan is to analyse the data and later create a GUI for it, so I can have better data visualisation. I'll research about sqlite.

Comment: Way, way too vague of a question. The answer depends entirely on your use case. That being said, I often find it easier to clean and aggregate data in a database instead of via Pandas/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the question is very general - it should be noted that the problems of *how do I store my dataset* and *what tool do I use to analyze my data* are very different questions.
Very often for datasets that need to be modified or updated at a regular interval a database will be preferable to i.e. a compressed file (since modifying the compressed file contents will require you to rewrite all of the data). For example I probably wouldn't use `sqlite` for an `nltk.corpus` although there maybe uses cases for that as well.

If you do decide to use with `sqlite` and your original data is in dictionary format, especially with many fields - 
You may find `exectrace` and `rowtrace` to be useful: 
http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/connection.html#apsw.Connection.setrowtrace
and 
http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/connection.html#apsw.Connection.setexectrace
useful.

For example to get rows out of `sqlite` in `dict` rather than tuple format, you may do:

```
def rowtracer(cursor, sql):
    dictionary = {}
    for index, (name, type_) in enumerate(cursor.getdescription()):
        dictionary[name] = sql[index]
    return dictionary

    con.setrowtrace(rowtracer)
```

And for inserts you can pass values in a dict by i.e.

```
"""insert into my_table(name, data) values(:name, :date)"""
```

Comment: There are many fields on the dictionaries, about 40 on total, but I probably will only need about 4-5 fields, so I reckon it must be easy to delete the unneeded fields from all dictionaries if their key values are the same? Also, is it possible to create a GUI to analyse the data from SQLite?